# AngularJS - follow scope in custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have custom directive and want to send some parameters(objects) to this directive.

In directive I have select list based on one of this parameters and I need to follow this parameter.

My directive:

```
<custom-directive rows="users">

</custom-directive>
```

and template:

```
<ui-select ng-model="value">
    <ui-select-match allow-clear="true">
        {{$select.selected}}
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="row in rows | filter: $select.search">
        <div>
            <span ng-bind-html="row | highlight: $select.search"></span>
        </div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

normally if rows change ui-select will automatically update select list. But if rows is variable from outside of this directive, it wont.

Can I have the same variable outside and inside directive?

I think I can use ng-model, but I'm not sure it is good solution.

EDIT:
My directive code:

```
.directive('custom-directive', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            rows: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            console.log($scope);
        }]
    };
})
```

Comment: show your directive code

Comment: I've edited post. Actually my directive is almost empty.

Comment: directive name is wrong on both html & in directive creation...it should be .directive('customDirective', function () {` & on html it should be `<custom-directive rows="users"></custom-directive>`

Comment: I've changed it for this site. Everything with that is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use link instead of the controller to handle functionality with rows. Setting rows : '=' should already take care of the two-way binding.

```
.directive('custom-directive', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
           rows: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            console.log(scope.rows);
        };
    };
})
```

EDIT:

Add a watch to the value that you need to do behavior on external change.

```
.directive('custom-directive', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
           rows: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch('rows', function(oldValue, newValue) {
                console.log('This is the newValue : ' + newValue);
            };
        };
    };
})
```

Comment: I was trying with link - it doesn't make change. Actually I need to have always actual value in template of this scope - in `template.html`. When something outside change(`users` variable) this change has to appear in `template.html`.

Comment: I updated my answer. My bad for leaving this out the first time. If you need behavior to happen on the update of the directive value based on actions outside of the directive you will need a watch.

Comment: Actually... I've deleted everything and done it again. It works now, but I don't know what's the difference. But it works:)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your custom directive to work with `ng-model` in the following way:

```
directive('customDirective', function() {
  return {
    // ...
    require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      if (!ngModel) return;              

      // Write data to the model
      // Call it when necessary
      scope.setValue = function(value) {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Initial state of `ng-model` value can be retrieved using that method:

```
ngModel.$render = function() {
    var value = ngModel.$viewValue || [];
};
```